# plot 'on/off' for different variables over time

Tags: r

I have a set of 70 traffic counters with data covering a year. Different traffic counters have collected data on different days.

I would like to plot a graph with each traffic counter on the y-axis, each day on the x-axis. Then if there are any data for any individual counter on any one day a (say) red circle is shown. If null for that day nothing is shown.

The idea is to give a quick visualisation of how often each of the counters is on.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct your logic along the following lines -

```
df <- data.frame(
  counterid = sample(1:10,50,replace=TRUE),
  daytaken = sample(1:10,50,replace=TRUE),
  somethingelse = sample(1:10,50,replace=TRUE)
)

unique(df[,1:2])
```

The `unique` statement outputs all unique combinations of `counterid` and `daytaken` which tells you whether the counter was on that day or not.

Comment: In the end I was able to use geom_tile to create the visualisation. Using 'fill'for the number of days per month/year the counter was on proved to be much clearer than a daily record.